# Ajax.ActionLink single record update in table row

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This project I'm working on is a modified version of nerddinner. I made it through the nerddinner project ok. I have upgraded to MVC4 and EF4(as far as I can tell). However, I'm trying to put the RSVP Ajax.Actionlink in the list of projects (what would be dinners in nerddinner). So, in the table of projects, one of the columns will be a reserve link for each row to reserve the project. However, it's updating the database with the one RSVP record, and then adding duplicate values to the database for every record that exists on the page (so currently pagesize + 1 including the original record that got RSVPed). So, in the example below 11 records are being added to the db with all the same values. I tried removing all the pagination code and then I get the entire recordset + 1 records added to the db. Everything displays correctly, I'm just getting all those duplicate records.

Since things appear to be working... sort-of, I don't know enough how to troubleshoot this or even where to begin looking. I've done several google searches without finding anything similar to what I'm running into.

Anyone know where my fault is? ...or a better way to accomplish this(with an example)? I just assumed I could drop that code in the table, give each row specific div ids for `projectmsg` and all would be ok. But, something is looping back through and adding all those extra records too.

Here's what I have in the way of code:

Index.cshtml

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ProjectSender.Models.Incident>
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.IncidentId })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Partial("_ReserveStatusList", item)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

_ReserveStatusList.cshtml partial view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ProjectSender.Models.Incident>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="projectmsg_@(Model.IncidentId)">


        @Ajax.ActionLink("Reserve this Project",
                             "RegisterAjax", "Projects",
                                      new { id = item.IncidentId },
                             new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "projectmsg_@(Model.IncidentId)"})

</div>
```

IncidentsController

```
...
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, int? page)
        {
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            IQueryable<Incident> incidents = null;

            incidents = incidentRepository.FindRecentIncidents(searchString);

            return View(incidents.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

RSVPController

```
...
    //
        // AJAX: /Incidents/RegisterAjax/1
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterAjax(int id = 0)
        {
            RegisterProject(id);
            return Content("RSVP Sent...");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Incidents/Register/1

        [HttpPost]
        private void RegisterProject(int id = 0)
        {

            Incident incident = db.Incidents.Find(id);

            if (!incident.IsUserRegistered(User.Identity.Name))
            {
                Project project = new Project();
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    IUserIdentity user = (IUserIdentity)User.Identity;
                    project.IUserId = user.Name;
                    project.IUser = user.FriendlyName;
                }
                incident.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: 5 days and no answers or comments... so now I have to wonder if I'm just way off base... or people really don't know... or possibly because I posted it on the beginning of the weekend...or it's not worth the effort... or? There was a rejected edit, that told me to remove the Httppost in the rsvp controller, but that didn't solve the extra records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stepped away from this checking this page daily for any life. I decided to give it one more go and figured out what the issue is, although I'm not exactly sure as to why.

Anyway, at the top of the partial view, I put that script reference:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I inspected the element in the browser, I could see it repeating in the html all the way down the page (one for each row...and the parent). Once I removed the reference on the partial view and just left the reference on the parent, the duplicate records in the db issue disappeared. So, my best guess is that it was executing for each script reference on the page.